# Hide span parent with jQuery if the span contains less than 3 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, contains

This is driving me nuts... But I surely miss something.

So the HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Product spec name</span><span>232112412</span></li>
  <li><span>Product spec name</span><span>cm</span></li>
  <li><span>Product spec name</span><span>80 cm</span></li>
  <li><span>Product spec name</span><span>75 cm</span></li>
  <li><span>Product spec name</span><span>cm</span></li>
</ul>
```

So what I want to achieve is to hide those list elements where the second span contains less than or equal to 2 characters.
I thought about putting them into a variable, loop through them, and if the length of the current item is less than or equal to 2 then jQuery should hide its parent.

Heres the code I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var pspec = $('ul li span:nth-child(2)');

     for(i=0;i<pspec.length;i++) {
        if($(pspec[i]).text().length <= 2) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
     }
});
```

But this code won't do the trick... I still consider myself a jQuery beginner so please would You be so kind to help me out on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Best Wishes,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PFaav/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('ul li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('span').eq(1).text().length <= 2;
  }).hide();
});
```

Your code will work if you replace

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

by this

```
$(pspec[i]).parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `jQuery` `each` instead of using `for` and mixing jquery and javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var pspec = $('ul li span:nth-child(2)').each(function(){    
        if($(this).text().length <= 2) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each ($('ul li'), function (idx, el) { 
        var $span = $(this).find('span').eq(1);  //2nd span
        if ($span.text().length <= 2) { 
           $span.parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the filter function

```
$('ul li span:nth-child(2)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length < 3; // <-- get 2nd span elements whose text length < 3
}).parent().hide();​ // <-- hide parent elements of the returned elements
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9dSU/